# Xcode 6.3 and Crashlytics / Other crash reporting tool

Tags: ios8, xcode6, crash-reports, crashlytics, xcode6.3

In the past you can only have one crash reporting tool in the App.

In the release notes for Xcode 6.3, I do see that "[Xcode 6.3 includes] a new feature to help **opted-in** App Store users and TestFlight users collect and analyze crash log data for your apps."

It would be nice to continue using Crashlytics for users that are **not opted-in**.

**Question:**  Can I continue to use Crashlytics / other crash reporting tool in conjunction with Xcode 6.3 crash reporting tool flag turned on?  Please share your experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have successfully used Crashlytics and turned on the feature for opted-in App Store users to send crash reports on iOS and receive crash logs in both areas.  The same applies for our Android app on the Google Play store (where I use PhoneGap/Cordova 3.6.x)

I noticed, however, that Crashlytics will show significantly more crash logs than Apple's reportings (due to the nature of not opting-in) so I rely heavily still on Crashlytics for error reporting.  The new feature in Xcode 6.3 is pretty neat for tracking crashes, but I personally haven't explored the feature in full detail.

To answer your question though - **Yes** you can have both on and they will both work seamlessly.

Also you should make the upgrade to Fabric if you haven't already, it's pretty painless now to do and if you ever need Twitter integration or analytics for Twitter ads in the future Fabric has it built-in.